# PHP PDO query SQLSTATE[42000] error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I had to build quick pdo query (this is very old site, using framework is not possible), and I have problem when I enter more then one parameter for search.

(for the single param it is working fine, but combining two or more params will give SQLSTATE[42000] error).

Complete error:

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or
 access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
 MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE CUSTPHON.PHONE = '1230001343' 
        GROUP BY CUSTOMER.CUST_ID
        ORDER BY CUST' at line 7' in /home/larrysii/public_html/yaclib/lib/db.php:104
```

Line 104 in db is for executing query:

```
public function execute(){
        return $this->stmt->execute();
    }
```

What is wrong here?

I am getting data from the form like this (I don't know which param will be used):

```
$searchParams = [];

    if(strlen($_POST['customerName']) > 2)
        $searchParams['customerName'] = strtolower(strip_tags(trim($_POST['customerName'])));

    if(strlen($_POST['cardNumber']) == 7)
        $searchParams['cardNumber'] = strtolower(strip_tags(trim($_POST['cardNumber'])));

    if(strlen($_POST['phoneNumber']) > 3)
        $searchParams['cardNumber'] = strtolower(strip_tags(trim($_POST['phoneNumber'])));

    if(strlen($_POST['customerAddress']) > 3)
        $searchParams['customerAddress'] = strtolower(strip_tags(trim($_POST['customerAddress'])));

    if(strlen($_POST['customerEmail']) > 2)
        $searchParams['customerEmail'] = strtolower(strip_tags(trim($_POST['customerEmail'])));
```

And this is how I make query:

```
$queryArray = [];

    foreach($searchParams as $key => $value):

        switch ($key):
            case 'customerName':
                $queryArray['customerName'] = " WHERE LOWER(CUSTOMER.LAST_NAME) LIKE ? ";
                break;

            case 'cardNumber':
                $queryArray['cardNumber'] = " WHERE CUSTPHON.PHONE = ? ";
                break;

            case 'phoneNumber':
                $queryArray['cardNumber'] = " WHERE CUSTPHON.PHONE = ? ";
                break;

            case 'customerAddress':
                $queryArray['customerAddress'] = " WHERE LOWER(CUSTADDR.ADDRESS) LIKE ? ";
                break;

            case 'customerEmail':
                $queryArray['customerEmail'] = " WHERE LOWER(CUSTOMER.EMAIL) LIKE ? ";
                break;

        endswitch;

    endforeach;
```

Getting the query:

```
$queryString = implode(' OR ', $queryArray);

    $query1 =  "SELECT CUSTOMER.LAST_NAME,CUSTOMER.DOB,CUSTOMER.EMAIL,CUSTPHON.PHONE,CUSTOMER.CUST_ID,CUSTOMER.DATE_LAST,CUSTOMER.ORD_COUNT
        FROM CUSTOMER
        RIGHT JOIN CUSTPHON
        ON CUSTOMER.CUST_ID=CUSTPHON.CUST_ID
        RIGHT JOIN CUSTADDR
        ON CUSTOMER.CUST_ID=CUSTADDR.CUST_ID
        {$queryString}
        GROUP BY CUSTOMER.CUST_ID
        ORDER BY CUSTOMER.LAST_NAME
        ";

    $pdo->prepareQuery($query1);

    $i = 1;

    foreach($searchParams as $key => $value):

        switch ($key):
            case 'cardNumber':

                $cardNumber = $value;

                if(strlen($value) == 7)
                    $cardNumber = '123' . (string)$value;

                $pdo->bind($i, $cardNumber);

                break;

            case 'customerName':
            case 'customerEmail':
            case 'customerAddress':
                $pdo->bind($i, "%$value%");
            break;

        endswitch;

        $i++;
    endforeach;
```

Comment: Got a *complete* error message for us so we don't have to look up what `42000` is exactly?

Comment: why so many `WHERE` entries? It would be nice to see the sql statement once it is ready to be executed. Also, the entry for `phoneNumber` references `cardNumber` ~ `$queryArray['cardNumber'] = " WHERE CUSTPHON.PHONE = ? ";`??

Comment: Hmm, I think this is the case (extra where). I need to check this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error seems to be that you have multiple WHERE clauses.

Try this to build your WHERE clause :

```
$queryArray = [];

    foreach($searchParams as $key => $value):

        switch ($key):
            case 'customerName':
                $queryArray['customerName'] = " LOWER(CUSTOMER.LAST_NAME) LIKE ? ";
                break;

            case 'cardNumber':
                $queryArray['cardNumber'] = " CUSTPHON.PHONE = ? ";
                break;

            case 'phoneNumber':
                $queryArray['cardNumber'] = " CUSTPHON.PHONE = ? ";
                break;

            case 'customerAddress':
                $queryArray['customerAddress'] = " LOWER(CUSTADDR.ADDRESS) LIKE ? ";
                break;

            case 'customerEmail':
                $queryArray['customerEmail'] = " LOWER(CUSTOMER.EMAIL) LIKE ? ";
                break;

        endswitch;

    endforeach;
```

And this to build your query :

```
$queryString = implode(' AND ', $queryArray); // Or you can use ' OR ', depending on what results you want

$query1 =  'SELECT CUSTOMER.LAST_NAME,CUSTOMER.DOB,CUSTOMER.EMAIL,CUSTPHON.PHONE,CUSTOMER.CUST_ID,CUSTOMER.DATE_LAST,CUSTOMER.ORD_COUNT
    FROM CUSTOMER
    RIGHT JOIN CUSTPHON
    ON CUSTOMER.CUST_ID=CUSTPHON.CUST_ID
    RIGHT JOIN CUSTADDR
    ON CUSTOMER.CUST_ID=CUSTADDR.CUST_ID
    ' . ($queryString != '' ? ' WHERE ' . $queryString : '') . '
    GROUP BY CUSTOMER.CUST_ID
    ORDER BY CUSTOMER.LAST_NAME
    ';
```

Comment: As @RamRaider noted, you may also need to check your "CardNumber" and "phoneNumber" conditions, they are the same.

Comment: The extra WHERE was the problem. phoneNumber and cardNumber are different fields in the form, but it is the same field in the table (tried to explain this to client, but he still wants two fields (not my project, just trying to update the search)). Thanks for the help :)

Comment: Now I have to see why it takes a long time to run the query when I use cardNumber/phoneNumber.

Comment: That's a whole other problem, you'll need to open a new question if you're stuck on this.